# whoch of the following three holds?

Tags: functions

there exist a map $f: Z\to Q$ such that

1) is bijective and increasing

2) is onto and decreasing

3) is bijective and $f(n)\ge 0$ if $n\le 0$

4) has uncountable image

i know 4) is false because subset of a countable set is countable.

any hint for other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about rearrangement of the squence f(n) : $\mathbb{Z}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{Q}$ with the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ has same cardinal.